# How to get an option value from a database?

Tags: database

I have database named employee-application. It has 3 tables as follows

```
create table departments
(
 department_id int(20) not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 department_name varchar(30)  not null
);

create table designation
(
 designation_id int(20) not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 designation_name varchar(30) not null
);

create table employee
(
 employee_id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 employee_name varchar(30) not null,
 department_name varchar(30),
 designation_name varchar(30),
 salary int(20) not null,
 FOREIGN KEY(department_name) references departments(department_id),
 FOREIGN KEY(designation_name) references designations(designation_id)
 );
```

I want to create a form for adding a new employee to the table. How do I get department_name and designation_name to my form as option/dropdown values from the database?

Comment: Create a separate maintenance form for departments and designation.

Comment: I did that. All i need now is how to fetch option value from database?let your ans be specific to my question

Comment: Just perform a simple SELECT query then display a select with what you got from db. It's basic stuff with PHP and database, do some search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your employee table is not normalised, instead of using department_name and designation_name you should use department_id and designation_id.

In order to get list of designation names and department names as select box, you need to fetch department table and get all the rows e.g

### Department:-

```sql
SELECT department_id, department_name 
FROM departments 
ORDER BY department_name ASC;
```

get result and loop in layout to set department options.

### Designations:-

```sql
SELECT designation_id, designation_name 
FROM designation 
ORDER BY designation_name ASC;
```

get result and loop in layout to set designation options.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Use the Below Code**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `departments` ORDER BY `departments`.`department_name` ASC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

   {

 $deparmentdrowdown=$deparmentdrowdown.'<option value="'.$row['department_id'].'">'.$row['department_name'].'</option>';

    }
```

Comment: '$con' is a connection Variable

Comment: share your HTML Code of form where you want to display these Drop down

Answer (score 0):

**For Designation Drop down List You Can use this**

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `designation` ORDER BY `designation`.`designation_name` ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
 $desigdrowdown=$desigdrowdown=.'<option value="'.$row['designation_id'].'">'.$row['designation_name'].'</option>';
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

A select statement can be used to extract the information from the departments table. W3Schools has a lot of useful information, look at the following two links.

[SQL Help](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)
[PHP Help](http://www.w3schools.com/php/)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).